# Http Post not found 500 error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to POST a JSON array to a controller action method and save it to the database.

This is the controller:

```
   public class Gitcontroller : Controller
    {
       public GithubContext _context;

        public Gitcontroller(GithubContext context)//the database context
        {
            _context = context;
        }
         [HttpPost]
         public IActionResult Updateto([FromBody] GitJSON gitjson)
        {

            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    _context.AddRange(gitjson);
                    _context.SaveChanges();//adding list to table.
                }
                return View();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                   return RedirectToPage("Error", ex);

            }
        }
 }
```

the database has a gitd table.

The ajax call:

```
 $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'http://localhost:60294/Git/Updateto',    
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                 datatype: 'JSON',
                 data: obj,
                       success: function (data) {
                            alert('Post Succesful');
                        },
                        error: function (data) {
                            alert('error');
                        }
                     });
```

Model:

```
   namespace Github.Models
{
    public class gitd
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string AvatarURL { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Score { get; set; }
        public DateTime Updatedat { get; set; }


    }
    public class GitJSON
    {
        public List<gitd> gitdList { set; get; }
    }
}
```

Json:

```
 gitdList: [
      {"AvatarURL":"https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/7849225? v=4","Name":"simplenlg","Score":22.82041,"Updatedat":"2018-07-21T10:58:33Z"},   
      {"AvatarURL":"https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/1123352?v=4","Name":"osgi.enroute","Score":7.6444883,"Updatedat":"2018-07-17T08:26:51Z"}
   ]
```

The build is successful but I am getting a 500 error saying failed to load resource.
Also when I run the Updateto in Interactive I get the following:

```
> (1,2): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HttpPostAttribute'
> could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
> reference?) 
(1,2): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HttpPost'
> could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
> reference?) 
(2,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name
> 'IActionResult' could not be found (are you missing a using directive
> or an assembly reference?) 
(2,41): error CS0246: The type or namespace
> name 'FromBodyAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using
> directive or an assembly reference?) 
(2,51): error CS0246: The type or
> namespace name 'GitJSON' could not be found (are you missing a using
> directive or an assembly reference?) 
>  + additional 6 errors
```

The namespace I am using:

```
> using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc; using Github.Models; using System;
> using System.Collections.Generic; using System.Linq; using
> System.Threading.Tasks; using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
> using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

Also the CRUD operations generated by scaffolding are present in a controller named:gitds-does it affect the result anyhow?I dont think it does as I have defined a controller,view for Gitcontroller action Updateto and I am also creating _context in Gitcontroller.

How do I resolve this?What does the 500 error mean and how come I am getting a successful build with compile errors.

Comment: check if json object is matching your GITJson model, also add the json obj and model to the question

Comment: I think it is:I will put up the model and json being sent in the answer too.

Comment: 500 error is a general error that can occur for lots of reasons.  In this case the service isn't running or the URL is wrong.  Probably localhost needs to be changed.  Local Host is define in the host file in the windows folder.  I would try hard coding the PC IP address instead of local host and see if that works url: 'http://localhost:60294/Git/Updateto',

Comment: Did you debugged your code in VS? Put a break point in first line of method `Updateto` and see how `gitjson` parameter is reached to the ASP.NET. This may help finding the issue.

Comment: First I would suggest you doing your request using an alternative tool (Postman, Insomnia, and alike) to verify if your problem is at the endpoint or ajax call. And if you are using the controller as an Api your POST should be to http://localhost:60294/Git (without the action name) unless you customize your route to do so. Regards.

Comment: @AfsharMohebbi i Tried debugging, found two possible reasons.` _context.AddRange(gitjson);` I assume  that the above statement saves the gitjson value to gitd table of the database. Could I be wrong here? Also @the breakpoint ` Object {gitdList: "[{"AvatarURL":"https://avatars1.githubusercontent.…"}` is the value of obj, could this be the reason?

Comment: @jdweng  I tried debugging it appears that model binding is not happening.Tried debugging, found two possible reasons.` _context.AddRange(gitjson);` I assume that the above statement saves the gitjson value to gitd table of the database. Could I be wrong here? Also @the breakpoint ` Object {gitdList: "[{"AvatarURL":"avatars1.githubusercontent.…"}` is the value of obj, could this be the reason?

Comment: @IteratioN7T   tried debugging it appears that model binding is not happening.Tried debugging, found two possible reasons.` _context.AddRange(gitjson);` I assume that the above statement saves the gitjson value to gitd table of the database. Could I be wrong here? Also @the breakpoint ` Object {gitdList: "[{"AvatarURL":"avatars1.githubusercontent.…"}` is the value of obj, could this be the reason?

Comment: It is not the object itself. It is the fact that the object cannot be cast to GithubContext.  You are using  _context.AddRange(gitjson); and AddRange is not finding an array.

Comment: @jdweng why is it so, how can I resolve it? Total beginner, Need help :)

Comment: There are multiple strange error in your post. "The type or namespace name 'xx' could not be found", for this kind error, How did you create your project? What is your `GithubContext`? Have you define `GitJSON` property in `GithubContext`? If not, you should not add `GitJSON gitjson` directly to `_context.AddRange`. Try `_context.AddRange(gitjson.gitdList);`

Comment: @Edward Hi, Github Context is the database context. This is my first project using Visual Studio, So don't know much. I have followed the tutorial on MSDN for Movies. As you said my Github context may be missing GitJSON property. I assumed since gitd is a table I have created using Database first approach and Gitjson is a model class that is a LIST of gitd class members, it'll be automatically defined in Github Context. the gitd class was generated when i created the gitd table following the tutorial. Gitjson is  a model class i added. How do I add this to the Github context?Beginner, Help!!!

Comment: There is no need to define `GitJSON`. Add `public DbSet<Gitd> Gitd { get; set; }` to `GithubContext`. You may consider sharing us your project through github.

Comment: @Edward this the project: https://github.com/itsmeabhilashgk/.NET, need help:)thankyou

Comment: Appears you are missing a Namespace for GitJSON object with in your GitController.  `using  Github.Models` is necessary...  That is the first part as for the 500 error won't know till you run again. Can you place a debug breakpoint at the controller near the `IF ` statement to see what is popping up as the error.. I am getting its something to do with how the JSON is being parsed.  As for the 500 error that indicates a server error, something is being handled right.

Comment: @mvermef hey,but I have used GitHub.models namespace. I'll place the breakpoint and see.Thankyou:)

Comment: OK so.. there were somethings that were missing and somethings that had me confused... I can upload a PR on your github respository or I can publish the changes here. 500 error was related to the method parameter being null and `return View();` that made absolutely no senses in a ajax call... And your database was never created cause the CLI Tools create the DB were never added for migrations

Comment: @mvermef Anything fine:) thanks a lot. PR would be awesome, hoping for it to become a tutorial of kind to anyone starting so.:)

Comment: for quickness in changes to get it working I moved the JS to the Index.cshtml but I can move it back so as to allow for a different method to pull the `RequestVerificationToken`.  PR is up... I will also push that other change.

Answer (score 0):

Pulled OP's source from his repository.  Found a `return` call that was unnecessary for the source associated to the `Updateto()` method.  Pushed a PR with associated changes.

https://github.com/mvermef/.NET/tree/master

[image: Image...]

Comment: thanks for the pull, I am getting the same error. Regarding the changes, I could not understand the following: 1. Omitting the Anti Forgery Token ,causes any errors?   2.I understand that DbSet represents a database entity and the name represents the table, `public DbSet<Github.Models.gitd> gitd { get; set; }` -`Github.Models.gitd` could this have caused errors?    3.After changing the code as you have suggested I am facing the same 500 error, the controller action parameter remains NULL.4.Why is [HttpPost] not recognized?   -regards

Comment: AntiForgery used for any post.  not that it will cause errors just good habit.  2) It would have in the future, but the table actually never got created at first runtime/first db access, the tools weren't present.  3) Not sure what the issue is on your end.  Did you pull my source, as you didn't merge the PR?

Comment: Also keep in mind the name of the parameter to pass via AJAX has to be the name of the parameter in the Method posted to..

Comment: hi thanks a lot after looking at the changes I realised I had made the stupidest mistake possible i.e. not include EF, the JSON was not being passed properly therefore model binding was failing. Thanks a lot for the help mate:).